# Dataset indices for predicted values is not matching with those for actual values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am a python novice who is trying to solve a regression problem with neural networks. I am at the stage where I want to plot the predicted vs actual followed by determining the regression coefficient.

Model training

```
#import statements 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
%matplotlib inline

#importing the dataset
data = pd.read_csv("PPV_dataset.csv")
X = np.array(data.drop(["PPV"],1))
y = np.array(data["PPV"])

#model training & prediction
nn = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), activation = 'logistic', solver = 'sgd')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)
nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = nn.predict(X_test)

#indices of test set
a = X_test
indices = []
for row in range(len(X)):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if np.all(a[i]==X[row]):
            indices.append(row)

#listing actual values in an array
actual_values = []
for i in range(len(indices)):
    actual_values.append(y[indices[i]])
```

Comparing actual to predicted values

```
len(actual_values)
13

len(pred)
12
```

Image of dataset
[image: Dataset]

Comment: Please paste your code inline. Don't provide images of code

Comment: I have now pasted sorry it's my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: did you got the answer

Comment: After going through my data I noticed that there are 2 data instances with the same feature values.  That was causing the size of  `actual_values` to be 1 more than that of `pred`

But this helped to evaluate model accuracy.
`from sklearn.metrics import r2_score`
`r2_score(actual_values,pred)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `matplotlib` and the `seaborn` libraries for plotting you graph,
and for coeficient  `r_sq = nn.score(actual_values, pred)`

I recommend using `seaborn.lmplot()` in your case

for roberts particular case I suggest:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218249/discussion-on-answer-by-divyessh-maheshwari-dataset-indices-for-predicted-values).